# remote does not work anymore

Tags: remote, osmc, lirc

I have my Raspberry Pi 3+ since 1 year and suddenly the remote that I use which was the one of my TV does not work anymore.
I find that a little weird because I didn't do anything so that work.
Can you help me?
The OS on my Rapberry Pi 3+ is OSMC/KODI. My TV is a Philips model n° 46PFL5507H/12.
I tried to map my remote, but my pi doesn't receive any signal.

Comment: if you recently sudo apt updated and upgraded, then new kernel etc might not like the old LIRCd.  If your TV is in the LIRC devices database, you can install it again.  Remember to use the most updated tutoriial, 2019 June something, if I remember correctly. And use the "Mode 2" command to make sure you get the space/mark signals.

Comment: Yes i update and upgrade recently

Comment: And how can i resolve that ?

Comment: This is the most up to date tutorial I know: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104554/lirc-tutorial-for-rpi2b-buster-too-old-problem. Good luck and cheers! :)

Comment: change the battery in the remote

Comment: I aldready did that but it not worked

Comment: Can you please edit the question and paste the content of your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to it? And please paste also the out of these commands to it: `iw dev` and `iw wlan0 info`.