# Problem with pigpio library and infrared emitter

Tags: raspbian, pigpio

I have installed an infrared emitter with the following tutorial:

https://www.instructables.com/id/Zero-to-Air-Conditioner-Controller-With-Raspberry-/

But I had trouble running the LIRC commands, so with the help of the pigpio library and this script in Python:

IR Record and Playback http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py

I had managed to set up my air conditioning.

After backing up and reinstalling the operating system (Raspbian Buster on RP3+B) I was not able to get my air conditioning to work.

I don't know if the problem is something electrical or something at the software level. I have controlled with a camera that the emitter emits when it executed the commands. I have in turn controlled the status of the pidgpio service and it returns this to me:

```
sudo systemctl status pigpiod

Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of pigpiod.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units
● pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/pigpiod.service.d
           └─public.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-02-04 09:22:20 -03; 4h 5min ago
  Process: 418 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pigpiod (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 452 (pigpiod)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 2200)
   Memory: 880.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/pigpiod.service
           └─452 /usr/bin/pigpiod

feb 04 09:22:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio...
feb 04 09:22:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio.
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Seba San Blas, Your IR project tutorial seems to be using an outdated LIRC driver.  The following two answers to a similar LIRC question might help:(1) LIRC Tutorial For Rpi2B+ Buster Too Old Problem - Viewed 444 times 2019oct13
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104554/lirc-tutorial-for-rpi2b-buster-too-old-problem/104613#104613

(2) Rpi3 LIRC Library and UART IR Transceiver Setup Problem - 2019sep11 Viewed 1,000 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem. / to continue, ...

Comment: References 3/3: (3) Raspberry Pi LIRC Zero to Air Conditioner Controller -Sanchezjjose 2018
https://www.instructables.com/id/Zero-to-Air-Conditioner-Controller-With-Raspberry-/

Comment: `I had managed to set up my air conditioning.` ... did you test it thoroughly after you set it up?