# LIRC sending error transmission failed

Tags: gpio, lirc

I am trying to set up and send IR-Signals with my Pi using LIRC I was already able to receive signals and to configure them as a remote device.
I followed this tutorial : https://gist.github.com/prasanthj/c15a5298eb682bde34961c322c95378b
and added the following lines to my /boot/config.txt

```
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=22
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=23
```

but when I try

```
irsend SEND_ONCE nameOfRemoteConf KEY_POWER
```

I get this error

```
transmission failed
Error running command: Input/output error
```

I tried some troubleshooting but nothing worked for me could it be that there is something wrong with the IR transmitter or its pinning?

Comment: My answer to the following problem might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108053/problem-with-pigpio-library-and-infrared-emitter

Comment: Or this answer of mine: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/raspberry-pi-3-not-lirc-not-running-working)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `CONST_LENGTH` flag in the config file
Change `RAW_CODES|CONST_LENGTH` to `RAW_CODES`