# How to use this IR Sensor as LIRC receiver for Rasberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, led, osmc, lirc

So, recently I went to an electronics store to buy an IR Sensor, so they gave me the next one: [IR Phototransistor NPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vInQL.png)

Then I went online to check how to build this, and to my surprise, I've found that a lot of tutorials are of the three leads, when I've got only two leads. I'm new in the electronics world, and I need help to use this IR Sensor as a receiver for Raspberry Pi. Does anyone know how to use it? (ex: Which leads do correspond to the three lead version, or which GPIO pins...)

Comment: Nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.  You need to read up about IR protocols.

Comment: But will it work as an IR receiver for LIRC?

Comment: Hi TutoInfo Shexph, Welcome and nice to meet you. You might like to read my answer to the following LIRC question to study how to use LIRC for Rpi. Your two leg guy should be TSAL6200, an IR emitting diode. And three leg guy are receivers. I would recommend to get kit with both UART based emitter and receivers. Most linux and raspbian guys use LIRC, but I would recommend Rpi newbies use UART.

Comment: But the vendor said its an IR receiver

Comment: Yes it is a receiver. No it will not work with lirc. You need a IR demodulator (3 lead) which strips the IR 38kHz carrier. Read up on IR.

Comment: it is unclear what you purchased .... do you have a part number? ... please add it to your question above

Comment: Reference 19 and Long Answer Update (5) 2019sep12 of my answer to the following LIRC question show pictures of both IR transmitter and receiver LEDs. This is also the UART based IR transceiver learning kit I am recommending to the IR newbies: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Thanks. 
I went to the vendor and resulted it was something like a PIR sensor. He exchanged it for a TSOP4838, that's a Receptor. Thanks for the Help