# Live Holographic Display

Tags: display, software-recommendation

I've seen others make a holographic display using a RPi, monitor, and a glass prism. The only thing the Pi is doing is playing back a pre-rendered video. But, is there a way/software program to convert live display feed into the 4-sided format used with the prism? I can imagine it being really cool to use the whole desktop in 3d, live (I don't expect things like *individual icons* in 3d, just the flat desktop). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Rpi based holographic stuff is interesting: (1) 3D Holographic Display with Gesture Controller Project:
http://ijesc.org/upload/869873393613a36b9b2701dc763cf369.3D%20Holographic%20Display%20with%20Gesture%20Controller%20(1).pdf This project using Rpi2/3Z, which I think can be updated to Rpi4B, LIRC based IR sensors can be replaced by UART based ones, UART Based (Non LIRC) IR sensors 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem/103465#103465,  / to continue, ...

Comment: Gesture sensor/board can be replaced by ADXL345 Acdelero/Gesture/Pointing  Module
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/33027402240.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.564b2b8dsSMrrk&algo_pvid=a9c2ac6a-141e-46cd-a369-4d3beaae19ea&algo_expid=a9c2ac6a-141e-46cd-a369-4d3beaae19ea-0&btsid=93d73eb0-d052-49b6-ba3d-db8abc91fd72&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_9,searchweb201603_53, (3) Atmega328P, also replaced Rpi4B for better system integration, (4) LCD by 7" Colour OLED.