# IR transmitter modules for Pi4

Tags: pi-4, lirc

Is anyone aware of any reliable ir transmitter modules for the pi4?

Looking for something pre-configured at the moment

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjOvqLW2p7nAhWFtO0KHTcxC-4YABABGgJkZw&sig=AOD64_0rAHfcWwYEhcIZ52dPus5NbsAmfQ&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjkuZvW2p7nAhWDr3EKHdcrAYUQww96BAgKEFg&adurl=

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable USB alternative: https://www.irdroid.com/usb-infrared-transmitter/