# Using LIRC on Lakka on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: boot, raspbian-buster, lirc, lakka

Please forgive my ignorance on this topic, I am new to Raspberry Pi and Linux as a whole. I am trying to get LIRC running on Lakka so that I can automatically transmit some infrared signals on boot. I have created an infrared remote by following [this](https://www.hackster.io/austin-stanton/creating-a-raspberry-pi-universal-remote-with-lirc-2fd581) tutorial, and tested it to ensure it is working on Raspbian Buster.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can offer some insight!

Comment: You need to use an up to date version of LIRC.  You might like to read the following for more details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 I don't see Lakka mentioned anywhere in that post, will this work on that OS? I have already made this work on Raspbian Buster, but can't get LIRC to install on Lakka.

Comment: Hi @user40857, Ah, sorry to have confused you.  My comment was to remind you that LIRC versions before 2019 very likely won't work for new OS versions like buster. So my answer only shows which latest version of LIRC I tried with buster and working OK. I must confess that I have no experience in Lakka. So I might have wrongly thought that Lakka is an game console emulation software that can be installed in buster.  But if Lakka is itself a standalone variant of linux, then my answer is useless for you.  My apologies. Good luck. Have a great day, and cheers.