# Some questions surrounding FC-51 IR sensor

Tags: sensor, arduino

I am looking into using the Ifrared sensor. But i found datasheet andinformation about the manufacturer scarce. I need to know if the sensor is rohs compliant and if it or the manufacturer has other security certifications. Do you know where i can look best?

thank you.

Comment: (2) Ref 21, 22 of the following might help. (2) EB IR is RoHS.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem/103465#103465

Comment: Which sensor, please?... "**the** infrared sensor" means nothing - there are thousands of them!

Answer (score 1):

Given this is basically two IR LEDs and a LM393 comparator, I think your only hope is to select a supplier off Alibaba and work with them.  Gut feel is you will get nowhere and would do better to build your own.

I think you would do better to ask this on the electronics forum rather than the Pi one as it’s not specifically a Pi question.

You can find the forum [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)