# lirc config file only producing zero

Tags: lirc

I have a little problem with my Raspberry Pi. I have installed `lirc` and then I have done the following.

Added

```
#added for lirc
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=23
```

to my `/boot/config.txt` and changed the `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf` file:

```
#driver          = devinput
#device          = auto
driver = default
device = /dev/lirc0
```

After rebooting i tested it by pressing one button

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/lirc $ mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc0
Trying device: /dev/lirc0
Using device: /dev/lirc0
space 16777215
pulse 9127
space 4474
pulse 620
space 517
pulse 616
```

and many more numbers, so I thought at least that works. But if I try to generate a config file with
`irrecord -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd.conf` only the following file is generated.

```
begin remote

  name  cheap_amazon_remote
  bits            0
  flags CONST_LENGTH
  eps             0
  aeps            0

  one             0     0
  zero            0     0
  gap          50000
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0
  frequency    38000

      begin codes
          KEY_F1                   0x0
          KEY_F2                   0x0
          KEY_F3                   0x0
          KEY_F4                   0x0
      end codes

end remote
```

And thats the reason the test with irw only shows KEY_F1 no matter what I press. I don't understand what I did wrong an would be gratefull for any help.

---

**Update**

Sadly the Answer from the comments didn't help me. I found this (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=235256) forum and followed the tutorial, because I also realised that with mode2 I also get a second pulse. Sadly it didn't work. I followed the tutorial until I need to install. It failed as told in the tutorial but with the following error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file ./liblirc0_0.10.1-5.2_armhf.deb given on commandline
E: Unsupported file ./liblircclient0_0.10.1-5.2_armhf.deb given on commandline
E: Unsupported file ./lirc_0.10.1-5.2_armhf.deb given on commandline
```

Then I tried to do the cp commands but my /etc/lirc folder only has the following content

```
hardware.conf  lircd.conf    lircmd.conf
irexec.lircrc  lircd.conf.d  lirc_options.conf
```

I don't understand how to fix this or what I did wrong.

---

**Edit**

```
uname -a 
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:45:19 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Well, if you are using the 3 year old jessie and following a 5 year LIRC old tutorial, then you won't have any luck. You might like to check out the following outdated update: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 What make you think that it's jessie?

Comment: @Ingo, (1) Ah, that is my short way of asking the following long questions: "Please tell me which Rpi version you are suing, which OS you are using: wheezy, jessie, stretch, or buster? which release date you are using?  which tutorial are you following?"  If he cares to read my old answer, he would know in the very beginning I would indicate which raspbian and which old LIRC post and tutorial I used, using $date, $uname -a" etc.

Comment: (3) In most of my CLI examples, I often start with a couple of lines such as ***date***, ***uname-a*** etc, so hopefully he might to do the same, and everybody knows which Rpi OS etc he is using,  (3) Of course I know it is unlikely that he is using the very old jessie, so I expect he will complain very loudly, "***But I am not using jessie: :(***". Then I would say: "I am very sorry, so it is not jessie, but then what is it? My apologies for making the wrong guess of the os your are using, ..."

Comment: I'm sorry I took so long to react, I don't have to much time due to College. Im sorry If my Question didn't provide sufficient information I'm quite new to the Pi world I didn't know what you ment by jessie and hadn't had the time to look up your answer,
just in case I used this tutorial https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/42716-infrarot-empfaenger-und-sender-mit-dem-raspberry-pi-ansteuern/
and by the OS I'm using I just used the raspbian from the noobs packet and "uname -a" got me this output 
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.118-v7+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:21:24 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux