# Raspberry Pi 4 InfraRed remote control configuration

Tags: raspbian-stretch, lirc

I am trying to set up an IR remote control to setup a play, pause, fastforward and rewind command for kodi.

I followed all the guide explaining here but with few success  [Gitgub-lirc-pi3](https://gist.github.com/prasanthj/c15a5298eb682bde34961c322c95378b)

only difference is that in `/boot/config.txt` I inserted `dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=18`

I have managed to retrieve some command from one remote control but when I run them they have no effect on RPi. The result of `irw` is:

> 0000000000000 00 KEY_VOLUMEUP elegoo

however no volume is turning up.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Perhaps your LIRC library and tutorial are outdated. This Q&A might help: Rpi3 LIRC Library and UART IR Transceiver Setup Problem Asked 1 year, 6 months ago Active 10 months ago Viewed 4k times: 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you sirs, I have found an answer here: https://peppe8o.com/setup-raspberry-pi-infrared-remote-from-terminal/amp/

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer via this website [Setup Raspberry PI Infrared Remote from terminal](https://peppe8o.com/setup-raspberry-pi-infrared-remote-from-terminal/amp/) . All credits go to the creator of the page.