# Want to increase range of IR transmitter

Tags: lirc

I'm using this IR transmitter with my raspberry pi zero
https://www.dx.com/p/produino-ir-transmitter-module-for-arduino-blue-works-with-official-arduino-boards-2038634.html

I have the VCC and GND hooked up to the 5V and GND on the pi, and a PGIO pin hooked up to SIG.

I've got it working where I can control my device with the pi, but the problem is the range isn't very good at all. I have to have it really close to the device for it to work, much further than the actual remote.

I'm trying to figure out what an easy solution would be. I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to circuit design, so I'm not sure if there is something easy I can do or not. I'm wondering if I can add a battery somehow maybe, or if I need to just buy something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "really close"? Does product sheet says 10  metres?

Comment: It has to be like like under 1m or 1.5m to work. I can't find a distance listed.

Comment: Well, your datasheet says the following ***...IR emission distance: 10m;...***. My answer to the following question might help. 
Rpi3 LIRC Library and UART IR Transceiver Setup Problem Asked 1 year, 6 months ago Active 10 months ago Viewed 4k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem Cheers.