# Control IR Port With GPIO

Tags: gpio, hdmi

I'm working on a project that needs the ability to control an HDMI switch programmatically. There are going to be a lot of these boxes so price of the components used is very important.

I've experimented with automatic HDMI switches but I can't seem to get the level of control I need. I'm thinking about using a switch with a remote control but hardwire it to the GPIO.

The idea is I can hardwire from the GPIO to the IR socket and simulate the and be able to make the switch change inputs. I'm looking at using [this specific HDMI switch:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0739GSKV2)

Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: the following might help: (1) Rpi3 LIRC Library and UART IR Transceiver Setup Problem Asked 1 year, 3 months ago Active 6 months ago Viewed 3k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem/103465#103465

Rpi3B+ GPIO Controlling Remote IR Controller Problem Asked 6 months ago Active 6 months ago Viewed 121 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112780/how-can-rpi3b-gpio-input-ir-signals-direct-from-optoma-hx180x-projectors-remot. Cheers.

Comment: This HDMI switch DIY Q&A post might also be helpful: Rpi UART control IR Remote HDMI switch problem - Asked 1 year, 6 months ago Active 1 month ago Viewed 1k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99823/how-can-rpi-uart-control-an-ir-remote-hdmi-switcher

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? It seems like there should be a good enough solution,  but I don't know enough about IR to find it.

Comment: nope, I moved onto another solution. A friend of mine has some skill with electronics and wired a hdmi switcher from Amazon to the pins on the pie so I can control it that way. It's not bullet proof but it works as a PCO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to connect an IR LED and some circuitry to switch it from a Pi GPIO (an IR LED needs more power than can be supplied by a PI GPIO).

If you search for IR blaster and Raspberry Pi you may find some ready made products and/or designs for ones you can build yourself.

Once you have this hardware you will be able to send the IR commands using software on the Pi.

You should be able to find lots of similar projects if you search.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I'd like to skip over the sending of the IR signal and have a hardwire between the PI and the device. The HDMI switch has a plug for the IR receiver. I was thinking remove the IR receiver and  wire it directly to the GPIO. The finished product would be housed together so using IR seems like more trouble that it's worth

Comment: Do you know what the output of the IR receiver is?  Without that (both data protocol / structure / hardware pin out / voltages etc) our guess is as good as yours...  Even 'posh' audio systems have IR links in the same cabinet (B&O being a classic one for this in their older systems).  Great thing about *standards* - there are so many of them to choose from...

Comment: @Kywillis: "`I should have been more specific`". I agree. Were you aware that you may edit your own question to correct errors?

Comment: @Andyroo - I don't have that information currently. My plan was to verify this was possible and then pick an HDMI switch that this would work with best. It sounds like I'll need to buy the switch and then do testing with the remote to better understand what I need to replicate.

Comment: @Seamus - that's a good point, I've edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: @Kywillis - Theoretically anything is possible - cost is normally the limiting factor :-). Getting 'back end' details for most modern equipment is very hard so I find it easier / cheaper to replicate the IR when needed.